# RegEx not matching the last line in a MT940 statement :86: tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following RegEx: https://regex101.com/r/GMuKFI/2

I want to be able to also match the last line of the `:86:` tag line (there can be up to 4 lines, if I am not mistaken). Currently, I am not matching the last two lines, only the first two lines. I have tried using all kinds of combinations using `\S\s`, etc. But I couldn't reach the point where I am in a place to match the two lines. I tried positive forward looking, no avail.

My RegEx: `:([0-9]{2}[A-Z]?):(.*(?:\r?\n)?(?:(?!:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:).*)?)`

One more condition: it should not match the `-}` in the last line. Forgot to add this.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/GMuKFI/3

Comment: @revo, thanks a lot, this seems to be working. Is there a way to prevent it from matching the last line `-}` as well?

Comment: Yes add this to the negative lookahead: `|-}`

Comment: Thanks! This works: https://regex101.com/r/GMuKFI/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there and only need a quantifier for matching the next lines:

```
:([0-9]{2}[A-Z]?):((?:.*[\r\n]*(?:(?!:[0-9]{2}[A-Z]?:|-}).*))*)
                  ^^^^                               ^^^    ^^^
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/cGLBeD/1)